# whats the best way to parse a huge sql file

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

I am trying to parse a large sql file to a csv file. I have considered using fread in php but cant figure out if sql is separated by lines...bc I am assuming that fread is loading the data into RAM and that would not work.

Any ideas on how quickly convert sql to csv? (also I am running on a different machine than my db is on...so I cant export as csv unfortunately).

Comment: What's in this SQL file?  INSERT statements from a MySQL data dump?  The format will depend on the source.

Comment: Are you able to query the actual database as opposed to parsing a sql file?

Comment: I can query the database...however it is very large. I tried mysqldump but the tab delimiting file option only works when you are on the same servers as the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install mysql on your local machine. now you can import the sql file, then freely export as csv or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

"Large" - what does it mean to you.
You can save to a file on server (the machine DB is running) and compress/download.

Exaple:

```
SELECT name,lastname,age FROM profile
```

The query returns three columns of the mysql table. Now for redirecting/print into a file:

```
SELECT name,lastname,age FROM profile INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/userdata.txt'
```

This will output data into the passed file in the above statement. 
To output data in terms of CSV format add more options to the query as following:

```
SELECT name,lastname,age FROM profile INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/userdata.txt'
    FIELDS enclosed by '"' separated by "," LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

[original post](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?79,150417,285428#msg-285428)

Comment: 45 million rows...I will crash the db if I try to select everything. I am using aws's RDS which means I cant save anything to the server running the database...I think I am limited to conversion after I have exported from the RDS.